# Flutter | How to store login response in SQFlite database

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

Here I am doing login when I am logged in successfully it will store all the info in SQFLite database.
here is my login response where I don't know how to store string array and JSON in flutter SQFlite. I need to store all this response info in SQFLite.

Can anyone helps me to create a table based on this response?

```
{
  "loginUser": {
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiZTMzLTQ4NmItYmFhNS0wODRhMWI2Nzg3YjQiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.bLKz-y9W6VKXRXkG6fbxlrmcowRNupKL0g",
    "user": {
      "aclRoleId": [
        "cmr",
        "bsp"
      ],
      "confirmationSentAt": "2019-12-30T09:12:08Z",
      "confirmationToken": "$argon2id$v=19$m=131072,t=8,p=4$WQoFfhBUfabw7g1BgNuuxg$BmUEYNWTZHeCnY0xCqOT+nWEDNlXcrNIEWQZkA51oCk",
      "confirmedAt": null,
      "country": {
        "capital": "New Delhi",
        "code": "IND",
        "contactInfo": null,
        "currencyCode": "INR",
        "currencySymbol": "₹",
        "id": "3",
        "isdCode": "+91",
        "name": "India",
        "officialName": "The Republic of India"
      },
      "currentSignInAt": null,
      "email": "john@mailinator.com",
      "failedAttempts": null,
      "id": "1",
      "language": {
        "code": "EN",
        "id": "1",
        "isActive": true,
        "name": "English"
      },
      "lockedAt": null,
      "meta": null,
      "mobile": "(999)-000-0040",
      "profile": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe"
      },
      "resetPasswordSentAt": null,
      "resetPasswordToken": null,
      "scopes": null,
      "signInCount": 12,
      "statusId": "confirmed",
      "token": null,
      "unlockToken": null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one way of doing it:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:utility_demos/user_management/user.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = new DatabaseHelper.internal();

  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  // create database
  initDb() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "main.db");
    var ourDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return ourDb;
  }

  // create tables
  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE User(uid INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, token TEXT, user TEXT)");
    // note that Im inserting password as plain text. When you implement please store it as a hash for security purposes.
  }

  // insert user to db when login
  Future<int> saveUser(User user) async {
    Database dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.insert("User", user.toMap());
    return res;
  }

  // retrieve user from db
  Future<User> getUser() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM User');
    if (list.isNotEmpty) {
      return User.fromJson(list.elementAt(0));
    }
    return null;
  }

  //delete use when logout
  Future<int> deleteUser() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.delete("User");
    return res;
  }

  // check if the user logged in when app launch or any other place
  Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.query("User");
    return res.length > 0 ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Here is the `User` model class:

```
class User {
  final String user;
  final String token;

  User(this.user, this.token);

  // here because of user object is too long Im storing it as string
  // and that is actually not a good way to do this because of when you want to
  // fetch user and handle information it will be very hard to do those and also when testing
  // please map other properties in your json to model and that's the best way.
  User.fromJson(dynamic obj)
      : this.user = obj['user'].toString(),
        this.token = obj['token'];

  String get getUser => user;
  String get getToken => token;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {'user': user, 'token': token};
}
```

Here I have created a simple widget tree to show you. How to store retrieved json object properties. Please note that I'm storing json `user` object as `String` because of its pretty long. Its better to create your model for all variables and map them. See comment in `User` class.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:utility_demos/user_management/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:utility_demos/user_management/user.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter SO answers sample snippet',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Future<bool> doLogin() async {
    String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/login_mock_data.json");
    final decoded = json.decode(data);
    try {
      if (decoded != null) {
        final user = User.fromJson(decoded["loginUser"]);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
        await dbHelper.saveUser(user);
        return true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return false;
  }

  // just to show you how to fetch from db
  Future<String> getLoggedInUser() async {
    bool isLoggedIn = await doLogin();
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      User user = await DatabaseHelper().getUser();
      return user.getToken;
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getLoggedInUser(),// this is also not a good practice :D, since each and every time build method execute this will invoke too.
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text("Something..."));
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // just to show you how to fetch from db
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return Center(child: Text("Logged in token: ${snapshot.data}"));
          }
          return Center(child: Text("Not logged in"));
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've already done this part. but I want to know how to create a table of this response.

Comment: @RutvikGumasana wait im updating the answer

Comment: @RutvikGumasana I updated the answer, please check. I havent tested it yet,

Comment: so here you've created a user table. so if i am having lot of filed in the model as you say I've created the model so. I've to add all the fields to create table or it will automatically create the table.??

Comment: can I share with you my code? can you just please help me with that. your small help can make my day.

Comment: @RutvikGumasana If you want to automatically create table according to your model you have to use a ORM. In Flutter there are few but I havent use them. Moor, sqfEntity and jaguar_orm.

Comment: can you please juse see my code? i'll share you my github repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205183/discussion-between-blasanka-and-rutvik-gumasana).

Comment: please check the chat